# in rails 3.2 how can I create a nested "form_for"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

- what is the basic syntax for the form?
- what "accepts_nested_attributes_for" is actualy doind ?
- what should be in my controller?
- here is whats curently in my form:

-

```
<% f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %><br />
<%= builder.label :content, "Question" %><br />
<%= builder.text_area :content, :rows => 3 %><br />
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following for "accepts_nested_attributes_for":

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1